# Mac flutter doctor error "version solving failed"

Tags: flutter

I had got a problem when i try to install flutter.
Here is the log.
Help me tks.

```
~flutter doctor
Downloading Dart SDK from Flutter engine 58a1894a1cd798de2f9a206f157a90d45944028b...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 93.6M  100 93.6M    0     0  7212k      0  0:00:13  0:00:13 --:--:-- 6959k
Building flutter tool...
Because flutter_tools depends on file 5.0.6 which doesn't match any versions,
  version solving failed.
Error: Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (9 tries left)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within your pubspec.yaml file. The dependency File 5.0.6 doesn't exist, double check your pubspec.yaml that you have entered the dependency correctly like so

```
file: ^5.0.6
```

Otherwise, if the problem persists, try downgrading to 5.0.5.